# android api 21/22, status bar icons don't show when statusBarColor is set to white

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-statusbar

API 21+ supports android:statusBarColor which I'm using and setting to white in my theme. On API 23 on my Nexus 6P the status bar icons show up with darker tint, so you can see them against the white status bar.

However on API 21/22, the icons are also tinted white so they disappear against the white background. From my understanding Google set status bar icons to white in Lollipop and advised against a white background. Is there anyway to setColorFilter() or do similar to the icons in the status bar?

Here's my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

If I change my android:statusBarColor to #cccccc, for example, then I will see the white status bar icons. But I would like to tint them dark gray and keep the status bar color white.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightStatusBar) attribute. I didn't test this but this should work.

Comment: I don't want a translucent bar

Answer (score 0):

Use this for dark button color :

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YourTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Use this for light button color :

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YourTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yea I had tried that already, but not working on my Samsung Note 4, API 21. might be a Note 4 specific issue...thx